# Syntax to return a on Objective-C class reference from a method?

Tags: objective-c, class

I did try to google this, but actually found nothing. Coming from a strong Smalltalk background, I thought the following would be fine:

```
#import "ValveTargetState.h"

- (id) targetStateClass {
    return ValveTargetState;
}

- (void) targetIsActive:(BOOL)isActive {
    self.targetState = [[[self targetStateClass] alloc] initValve: self isActive: isActive];
    [self.targetState push];
}
```

Basically, I've added a method, so that subclasses can tune what the `targetStateClass` is used. It was my understanding, that like Smalltalk, classes are objects too in ObjC. But Xcode tells me

```
Unexpected interface name 'ValveTargetState': expected expression
```

(for the `return ValveTargetState;` expression)

I think I'm missing something obvious, but what is it?

Comment: Your not returning an instance...

Comment: Aren't classes instances too? You can send messages to them...

Comment: The return value of `targetStateClass` should be `Class`, not `id`.

Comment: Why do you want that.  Rather than `[self targetStateClass]` just do `[self class]` if you want the class of the current object.  (Though it seems a little curious to create an instance of the class within an instance of the class.)

Comment: To clarify rmaddy's point a bit: `Class` is technically compatible with `id` — you can use it in `id`-typed variables and you won't get errors from it — but when you definitely intend to return a class, it's better to use Class for code clarity purposes.

Comment: My import is misleading there, sorry. The class is `Valve`. And this particular wants to use `ValveTargetState` to get this chunk of code done. But a subclass overrides the `targetStateClass` to return and use a different class to get the job done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `ValveTargetState` is a class that inherits ultimately from `NSObject`, either

```
[ValveTargetState class]
```

or

```
[ValveTargetState self]
```

will give you the pointer to the class object for `ValveTargetState`.

It would be much better to use `ValveTargetState` directly, but unfortunately the name of a class is not a valid expression in Objective-C.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
- (Class)targetStateClass 
{
    return [ValveTargetState class];
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `return [self class]`?

Comment: @rmaddy in honest, I don't understand what the topic starter wants to achieve. I just showed the the syntax to return class reference.

Comment: @rmaddy: Not necessarily. Almas' version is a direct fix of the OP code. `[self class]` would give exactly the same result for instances of ValveTargetState, but a different result for subclasses. It depends on whether he intends to specify ValveTargetState or if he just wants self's class, whatever that may be.

Comment: Agreed. It really depends on what the OP actually needs.